# Creating pyspark dataframe from same entries in the list

Tags: pyspark

I have two list, one is col_name=['col1','col2','col3'] and the other is col_value=['val1', 'val2', 'val3']. I am trying to create a dataframe from the two list with col_name being the column.I need the output with 3 columns and 1 row (with 1 header as a col_name).
Finding difficult to get the solution for this. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct `data` directly, and use the `createDataFrame` method to create a dataframe.

```
col_name = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
col_value = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

data = [col_value]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, col_name)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. So simple solution. I still don't understand why we need to copy it to another variable for it to work. Can you pls explain on this

Comment: Spark official documentation describes: ```Parameters:
data      RDD or iterable
an RDD of any kind of SQL data representation (Row, tuple, int, boolean, etc.), or list, or pandas.DataFrame.``` The element of ```list``` here cannot be a scalar. The common ones are list of tuple or list of list.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much...